# Unity C# error CS1525: Unexpected symbol 'Public'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to fix this error for a while now but I can't figure it out. I've searched on the web for a while too with no succes. Sorry if it's a obvious mistake, I'm pretty noob at programming.

http://pastebin.com/u7eCtmPW

If someone can help me, I'd be really gratefull!

Comment: in pretty much any language, if you get a syntax error with "unexpected foo", you probably forgot something on an EARLIER line of code, and "foo" is simply the first place where the parser noticed things went wonky.

Comment: **A)** Always post your code in your question. **B)** On what line does this occur???

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerator UpdatePath; {
```

This is your error in line 70.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I changed it but it gives me 3 more errors instead though.

Answer (score -1):

There are just many problems and most of them basic, to the extent that I recommend you stop whatever you are doing and learn basic programming before moving forward.

**1**.On *line 44*,  `StartCoroutine (SearchForPlayer);` should be `StartCoroutine (SearchForPlayer());`.

**2**.On *line 66*, `return false;` should be `yield break;` because `SearchForPlayer()` function is a coroutine function not a `bool` function.

**3**.`SearchForPlayer()` function does not have a closing braces. Add `}` on *line 68*.

**4**.`IEnumerator UpdatePath;` should be `IEnumerator UpdatePath()` on *line 69* just like [Gunnar B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38190768/3785314). mentioned in his answer.

**5**.Again `StartCoroutine (SearchForPlayer);` should be changed to                     `StartCoroutine (SearchForPlayer());` on *line 74*.

**6**.Change `return false;` to `yield break;`  on *line 77* because you are inside a coroutine function.

**7**.You misspelled `StartCoroutine`. Change `StartCoroutin0e(UpdatePath());` to `StartCoroutine(UpdatePath());` on *line 84*.

**8**.Change `StartCoroutine(SearchForPlayer);` to `StartCoroutine(SearchForPlayer());` on *line 99*.

**9**. ***IMPORTANT***: Stop and Learn C#. Start from [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting).

You can get the fixed version [here](http://pastebin.com/9kHqU8Te). Code should compile but that does not mean it would function the way you want it. Coding is step by step. You can't just write thousands of lines of code that does't compile then expect it to work as expected, later on.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to actually fix all of it. Second, it compiles now but now my game object doesn't follow my player anymore. It draws a path but it does not move however. Third, I know I suck at programming and got most of the code from an already written script,so yeah. I think i'll fully learn C# this summer through the link you sent me